# How do you extract the weight matrix and hyperparameters along with the layer parameters in Tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I saw [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) but I believe that doesn't solve my problem and I am worried that I might have to do surgery on Tensorflow to make the weight matrix and hyperparameters along with the activation function and layer parameters exportable and importable into the tensorflow session.  Anyone have any idea where to start?  I have dealt with other frameworks that allow you to save in HDF5 or Pickle for python 2.7+/3.5+ but TensorFlow is making it harder than it should actually be in this case.

I was told by the TensorFlow authors to ask this question on StackOverflow because it would be the best place to ask it since they cannot treat it as an issue but rather as an extra component or feature inquisition IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If by exporting you mean you just want to access the parameters, e.g. to make an image out of weight matrices, you can use `sess.run([parameter])` to get the values as a numpy array at any point after starting a session and initializing variables. If by importing you mean starting with certain values, perhaps you can use a [constant initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer) for simple cases. But savers are the way to go in general if you're trying to reload a previously trained net.